# Derived class design problem (Polymorphism)

Tags: c#, polymorphism

The design problem is as follows,  actual problem consists of 2 modules.

### Module 1 classes (External Assembly)

```
abstract class Letter
{
    private int _id;
    protected Letter(int id) { _id = id; }

    public abstract string Val { get; }
}

class LetterA : Letter
{
    public LetterA(int id) : base(id) {}

    public override string Val
    {
        get { return "A"; }
    }
}

class WordWithALettersOnly
{
    public IList<LetterA> ALetters { get; set; }
}
```

### Module 2 classes

```
class LetterSmallA : LetterA 
{
    public LetterSmallA(int id) : base(id) {}
    public override string Val
    {
        get { return "a"; }
    }
}

class WordWithSmallALettersOnly : WordWithALettersOnly
{
    private IList<LetterSmallA> _aLetters;
    public new IList<LetterSmallA> ALetters
    {
        get { return _aLetters; }
        set
        {
            _aLetters = value;
            if(_aLetters != null)
                base.ALetters = value.Cast<LetterA>().ToList(); // <-- reference lost
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var smallAWordOnly = new WordwithSmallALettersOnly();
        smallAWordOnly.ALetters = new List<LetterSmallA>(){new LetterSmallA(1)};
        Console.WriteLine("d : " + smallAWordOnly.ALetters.Count); // --> 1
        Console.WriteLine("b : " + ((WordwithALettersOnly)smallAWordOnly).ALetters.Count); // --> 1
        smallAWordOnly.ALetters.Add(new LetterSmallA(2)); --> 2
        Console.WriteLine("d : " + smallAWordOnly.ALetters.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("b : " + ((WordwithALettersOnly)smallAWordOnly).ALetters.Count); // -> 1 
    }
}
```

Essentially derived classes are generated in the module 2 and processed in the external assembly module 1, on a/c reference loss.

Is the only way to translate the derived class objects of the module 2 to module 1 class objects

I hope i have been explain clearly the issue, if not i do apologise, would really appreciate solutions to this.

Comment: what do you mean by saying "on a/c reference loss" ?

Comment: the .ToList() returns a copy rather than returning a casted reference,

Comment: essentially what i would like achieve is static type constraint, also by not using additional property

Comment: isn't this against the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle ?

Comment: thank you for the link ckoenig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is to treat `IList<LetterSmallA>` as `IList<LetterA>`. This is not possible in C# and for very good reasons: one of the things `IList<LetterA>` says is possible to do with is is to “try to add any `LetterA` to it. This is not possible with `IList<LetterSmallA>` and so there is no built-in way to do what you want.

What you can do is to create your own implementation of `IList<T>` that wraps another `IList<T>` of derived type:

```
class BaseTypeList<TBase, TDerived> : IList<TBase>
    where TBase : class
    where TDerived : class, TBase 
{
    private readonly IList<TDerived> m_derivedList;

    public BaseTypeList(IList<TDerived> derivedList)
    {
        m_derivedList = derivedList;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TBase> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return m_derivedList.Cast<TBase>().GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(TBase item)
    {
        var derivedItem = item as TDerived;
        if (derivedItem == null)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        m_derivedList.Add(derivedItem);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        m_derivedList.Clear();
    }

    // other members implemented in a similar fashion
}
```

(The `class` constraints are not necessary, but make some code simpler.)

Your setter for `ALetters` could then look like this:

```
_aLetters = value;
if(_aLetters == null)
    base.ALetters = null;
else
    base.ALetters = new BaseTypeList<LetterA, LetterSmallA>(value);
```

Comment: but then how would that solve the problem ? as i can not modify the external assembly, might as well just translate the module 2 class object into module 1 class object.

Comment: If you think my answer actually answered your question, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).